# SQL LIKE Command not including certain data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

My data is as follows:

> Name: Roger
>
> Occupation: Engineer
>
> Name: Jane
>
> Occupation: Engineer

Code:

```
string occ = "software engineers";
```

My SQL Command: (Removed Parameterized query just to make things clear for now)

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Occupation LIKE '%" + occ + "%'"
```

However this does not return the Users since an additional 's' is placed at the end of the parameter occ. If I change the value of occ to 'software engineer', it returns the two users. How can I change the query such that it includes all data that is similar to the parameter?

That is, include all users with an occupation of either 'software engineer' and 'software engineers'

Comment: Can you explain how server or your application will know which characters must be excluded from search parameter? SQL Server will perform search based on the given parameters. If you have logic how to create all possible variation of search parameter, then use it logic to create parameters for SQL query based on the user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem. You can't just tell the DB to give you any records that "kind of look like this search query".

You should probably define a bit better what kind of flexibility you are after.

For this specific example, and any others that like it differ only in a suffix, you could do

```
SELECT * FROM Users Where CONTAINS(Occupation,@occ)
```

So if the actual DB occupation **contains** the occ search query value anywhere in it, it will return that record.

Also note that I've used @occ
You should basically never do

```
"SELECT * FROM Users Where CONTAINS(Occupation," + occ + ")";
```

The absolute worst case is when "occ" is actually supplied from the user of your application, because this is a huge security vulnerability (SQL Injection)

But even if it's supplied from your own code somehow, you should still use SQL parameters to add the value to the @occ parameter.
Please look into sql parameters and how to use them.

Comment: Does `CONTAINS` function return something if `@occ = 'engineers'` and `Occupation` column conatins only `'software engineer'` text?

Comment: no. CONTAINS simply checks if the first parameter contains the second parameter anywhere in it. It can't take only parts of the second parameter to search within it. As I said, the OP needs to more specifically define what kind of search flexibility is needed. The DB can't figure it out on it's own. He can use stuff like contains, regex searches, replace certain characters, but in the end, he needs to define exactly how this is to be performed.

Comment: So how `CONTAINS` differ from `LIKE '%value%'`? I mean difference in the result, not performance or query plans. What difference between your solution with `CONTAINS` and OP's used approach with `LIKE`?

Comment: Which dbms has CONTAINS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Occupation LIKE '%" + occ + "%' OR " +
  ooc + " like '%' + Occupation + '%'"
```

Comment: please don't encourage string appending parameters from code. If not in this case, the OP will sooner or later write a similar query where the variable comes from user input.

Comment: I have shown the idea. Of course Op has to think abouta security.

Comment: @irreal As I have mentioned, I wrote a normal query so that my intentions are clear. I use parameterized queries no worries